# How can I call a method that are in my code-behind via Javascript or Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the follow line in my Javascript code

```
credenciadausuario = '<%= getCredenciada() %>';
```

In my code-behind I have this method

```
public string getCredenciada()
{
    Utilidade.QuebraToken tk = new Utilidade.QuebraToken();
    string credenciada = tk.CarregaToken(1, Request.Cookies["token"].Value);
    return credenciada;
}
```

but when I put the debugger in my javascript code, the credenciadausuario variable, receives the string "<%= getCredenciada() %>" and not the return of my method. How can I call my method that are in my code-behind via javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Yes, my code are in a .js file, so I call this file in my .aspx page

Comment: Looks like you are using some library that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: js files are not processed by .net so your method call is just treated as a string. If you want it to work it will have to be in the aspx page itself.

Comment: @jammon, I inherit from my master page.

Comment: @RichardD You're right, it works if I put in my aspx page the javscript, but javascript is javascrit, so I don't wanna separate my javascript code from my .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF possible make use of ajax and do call the method, that will do you task.

check this post : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html

**Cs File (codebehind)**

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string IsExists(string value) 
{     
    //code to check uniqe value call to database to check this     
   return "True";
 }
```

**Javascript**

```
function IsExists(pagePath, dataString)
 {
  $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url: pagePath,
     data: dataString,
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType:"json",
     error:
          function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {               
               alert("Error");
          },
     success:
          function(result) {
                  alert( result.d);

      }
     }
});}

      var pagePath = window.location.pathname + "/IsExists";
     var dataString = "{ 'value':'ab" }";
     IsExists(pagePath, dataString);
```

Comment: Calling my method via ajax will pass in my page_load ?

Comment: @asawyer, I wanna mean, how can I call a ajax to call my method that are in my code behind

Comment: He means: Pages cannot call functions on a server -- all they can do is POST/GET. If you use AJAX you can do this without reloading your page:

Comment: @PranayRana Works fine, I do some corrections to adapt to my project. Thank's.

Answer (score 2):

It seems all you want to do in your code is get the value of a cookie. Why not do that in JavaScript on the client?

Answer (score 1):

This article from [Encosia](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) is excellent. It shows how to call a method in your code behind using jQuery ajax.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

In your code behind you have to give the method the [WebMethod] attribute:

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
 {
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
     return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

To call that method using jQuery you would use the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/GetDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
   // Do something interesting here.
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to actually CALL your code-behind methods from Javascript, you would have to use ajax. JQuery has a nice $.ajax wrapper for that.

But I think you just want to include some value into the js code once, while it's being generated and sent to the browser. In that case, you need to use a file type which ASP.NET recognizes as a dynamic file.

The easiest would be to put JS code (in a `<script>` tag) into .ascx files. Then `<%= getCredenciada() %>` will be executed and will return an actual string which will be rendered into javascript code.

Then, of course, you should include such a control to the page as a regular ASP.NET control.

And I am not saying this is the best way to achieve what you want. Sometimes it's just the fastest.